# PDF box PNG image not supporting

Tags: java, png, pdfbox

I am using PDF box to create PDF, I am trying to print image into pdf , it works all the format except PNG. Mycode as follows :

```
String image = "c:/image.png";                  
                                   PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
                  if( image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpg" ) )
                  {
                      ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream( image ) );
                  }
                  else if (image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tif") || image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tiff"))
                 {
                      ximage = new PDCcitt(doc, new RandomAccessFile(new File(image),"r"));
                 }
                 else
                  {
                      BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( image ) );
                      ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
                      throw new IOException( "Image type not supported:" + image );
                  }

                 PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
                  contentStream.drawImage( ximage, 20, 20 );
```

When ever I give png image it is going to the :

```
else
                      {
                          BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( image ) );
                          ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);
                          //throw new IOException( "Image type not supported:" + image );
                      }
```

and showing image stream IO exception cant read image file. What changes am I need to make to accept png image also in this? Please help...

Comment: Because a file name ending in ".png" goes to your "else" block, and your else block always does a `throw new IOException( "Image type not supported:" + image );` as the third statement (not sure why you have two statements before it if you're going to throw an exception in every case)

Comment: yah I forget to remove that, now removed

Comment: @ Erwin Bolwidt showing image stream IO exception cant read image file!!

Comment: Is there a detailed message why it can't read the image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String image = "c:/"+rst.getString(8);                  
                                               PDXObjectImage ximage = null;
                                if( image.toLowerCase().endsWith( ".jpg" ) )
                                {
                                    ximage = new PDJpeg(doc, new FileInputStream( image ) );
                                }
                                else if (image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tif") || image.toLowerCase().endsWith(".tiff"))
                               {
                                    ximage = new PDCcitt(doc, new RandomAccessFile(new File(image),"r"));
                               }
                               else
                                {
                                    BufferedImage awtImage = ImageIO.read( new File( image ) );
                                    ximage = new PDPixelMap(doc, awtImage);

                                }


                               contentStream.drawXObject(ximage, 20, pageYaxis-120, 80, 80);
                                                pageYaxis = pageYaxis-56;
```